# How to give a frame as argument to DrRacket when I paint a image by using a painter? (SICP 2nd Edition)

Tags: racket, sicp

I am reading SICP 2nd Edition.

> A painter is represented as a procedure that, given a frame as argument, draws a particular image shifted and scaled to fit the frame.

I am using DrRacket (SICP Picture Language).

How to give a frame as argument to DrRacket when I paint a image by using a painter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

```
#lang racket
(require sicp-pict)
(paint einstein)

(paint
 (λ (f)
   (einstein (frame (vect 0. 0.) (vect 1. 0.) (vect 0. 1.)))))

(paint
 (λ (f)
   (einstein (frame (vect 0.5 0.5) (vect 0.5 0.) (vect 0. 0.25)))))
```

If you want all the gory details of the actual representation used:

https://github.com/sicp-lang/sicp/blob/master/sicp-pict/main.rkt